# jQuery jump or scroll to certain position, div or target on the page from button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

When I click on a button i want to be able to jump down or scroll to a specific div or target on the page.

```
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    //jump to certain position or div or #target on the page
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 47):

I would style a link to look like a button, because that way there is a no-js fallback.

---

So this is how you could animate the jump using jquery. No-js fallback is a normal jump without animation.

**Original example:**

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/ZVdRt/)**</kbd>

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".jumper").on("click", function( e ) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $("body, html").animate({ 
      scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top 
    }, 600);

  });
});
```

```css
#long {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Links that trigger the jumping -->
<a class="jumper" href="#pliip">Pliip</a>
<a class="jumper" href="#ploop">Ploop</a>
<div id="long">...</div>
<!-- Landing elements -->
<div id="pliip">pliip</div>
<div id="ploop">ploop</div>
```

---

**New example** with actual button styles for the links, just to prove a point.

Everything is essentially the same, except that I changed the class `.jumper` to `.button` and I added css styling to make the links look like buttons.

<kbd>**[Button styles example](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/ZVdRt/262/)**</kbd>

Comment: OP mentions they want to use a button.

Answer (score 34):

```
$("html, body").scrollTop($(element).offset().top); // <-- Also integer can be used
```

Comment: cant get that to work, where body is i have specified by div #goHere, i need it to scroll down the page to a specific div. cheers

Comment: hey, you have to replace `$(element)` with `$("#goHere")`. `$("body")` will remain as it is because we want to move scrollbar of body.

Comment: this code works great in chrome , but not in firefox, at least not in ff 21.0 :(

Comment: the fix is to add `$("body, html").scrollTop(...)`

Comment: I want to achieve this effect, but I'm a n00b. Where does this code go?

Comment: it works for me thanks

Comment: nice one liner ... helps when using it in the console