# Go back to N'th "page" of a page in Angular

Tags: angularjs, position

There is a page with thumbnails. At the bottom there is have a "Show more" button that loads more thumbnails. A user can click on a thumbnail and re-direct the application into details. When the user clicks browser's "back" I would like him to land in the same position as before. How to achieve this without complex routing?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like this using [angular-bootstrap-lightbox](http://compact.github.io/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/demo1/index.html) and the [ui-bootstrap pagination](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination). Both are Angular and use common resources

EDIT:

What you're looking for is something along the lines of [scroll-sneak](http://mrcoles.com/scroll-sneak/), you want to save the scroll position when you redirect to another page and load the last position when you redirect back.

since I could not find any angular directive to do so, you can either

1. get one and wrap it around a directive, most of them use jQuery
2. you can make your own.

for example, you can use js to define a queue array and store it in localStorage/sessionStorage, when you redirect "push" the current page location to the queue, when you redirect back, "pop" that last stored position.

[Maintain Scroll Position of large HTML page when client returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388772/maintain-scroll-position-of-large-html-page-when-client-returns)

Comment: I don't want to open the details page within the lightbox. I want it to remain a standalone page.

Comment: you mean just remembering the scroll position you were before you entered details?

Comment: Exactly, but, with the "sub-page" position within the page (so basically, how many times the user clicked "Show more").

Comment: Try scrolling down on Facebook and wait for example five times for something to load. Then click on a random date of a post (to go to the details page). Then go back. It automatically loads so many posts that you get to your previous position.