# scroll to specific element on page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello am having a great problem scrolling the page to a specific element on page using jquery or javascript.

I've tried many ways of doing it but i failed in all of them. the website is implemented using the framework library called curtain.js https://github.com/victa/curtain.js.

The ways I have tried include:

1)https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.scrollIntoView

2)[How to go to a specific element on page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-a-specific-element-on-page)

3) I even tried the simplest way using  anchor tags but nothing happens.

the **only** way that **worked** was scrollTop() as you can see from other links on the page. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me since this fails on different screen sizes.

you can see example of the site at http://pagota.herobo.com

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158937/jquery-jump-or-scroll-to-certain-position-div-or-target-on-the-page-from-button/15159396#15159396

Comment: You want to scroll(slide) to specific page, right? curtain.js is using <li> tag as full screen.

Comment: @Joonas I tried the first example of the post u sent me but it gives me TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is null

Comment: It gives you that error in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/ZVdRt/? or the code gives you error after you implement it into your website?

Comment: after i tried it in my website

Comment: It seems like it is not finding the offset of your element for some reason. Try isolating the issue by first trying that code in a simple document with just the bare essentials.

Comment: use http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: If `.offset` returns null, then you are trying to select the element before it exists. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element.

Comment: @ak_47 If you want menu, add a menu outside of ol, then add links with your li page id in href. Check my answer in answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE

Try this one, if you want a menu and menu links to specific page. It will scroll to your page with curtain effect.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/mCytP/2/

Add `menu` outside of `ol`, then add links with your li page id in href.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" class="curtain-links curtain-links-active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about_us" class="curtain-links">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" class="curtain-links">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#programs" class="curtain-links">Programs</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```