# ScrollTop to desired location not working incase of iPad

Tags: php, jquery

I have following code to scroll the desired section targeted by **attr**

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $( attr).offset().top -300
}, 500)
```

Page successfully scrolls to that position in desktop but not in iPad. I will have to update the value from **300** to suitable values for iPad. How can i make it dynamic so that it works correctly in all the devices?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $('#tagID').offset().top 
}, 2000);
```

Try this... add your target ID or Class.

Comment: I need to show my targetted id in the middle of screen or to the defined position thats why i used 300. But in ipad it shows at desired position of mine when value is 200.. how to make this dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

pls refer

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/ZVdRt/

[jQuery jump or scroll to certain position, div or target on the page from button onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158937/jquery-jump-or-scroll-to-certain-position-div-or-target-on-the-page-from-button)

for example.

```
$("body, html").animate({ 
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top 
}, 600)
```

Comment: This way takes to that element but i want to show at the position defined by $( attr).offset().top **-300**